# Is there any way of converting a string containing es6 to es5?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am creating an application where a user will enter es6 code and my application will return es5 equivalent. I know babel converts es6 to es5 but is there any way to use it for strings that contain es6 code.

e.g
Input:

```
"[1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 2)"
```

Output:

```
"[1, 2, 3].map(function(n) { return n * 2; }, this)"
```

Comment: babel.js  would be helpful.

Comment: but is there any way for doing it where code is a string

Comment: You can use their API. https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/ It will allow you to pass a string and in return it will give you the code in ES5/ES6.

Comment: I don't understand your "where the code is a string" distinction.  Isn't all Javascript code essentially a string?

Comment: @RobertHarvey OP might be having code as a string. `var code = "hai()";` And I guess he wants to convert it to ES6/ES5.

Comment: Babel JS has a "try it out" page on their website which does exactly the same thing that you are trying to implement. So yes, obviously it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "transpiling". Transpilers are programs those transfers a code written in a language to another language at the same level of abstraction. (From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler))

For ES6 to ES5, as you mention in your question, there is a tool named [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

From the [Babel's documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/):

> ```
> var babel = require("babel-core");
> ```
>
> #### babel.transform(code, [options])
>
> Transforms the passed in code. Returning an object with the generated code, source map, and AST.
>
> ```
> babel.transform(code, [options]) // => { code, map, ast }
> ```
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> var result = babel.transform("code();", options);
> result.code;
> result.map;
> result.ast;
> ```

Comment: Can you provide what exact options to put in

Answer (score 1):

You need to install both babel-core and babel-preset-2015

after

```
var babel = require('babel-core');
```

if you enter into node

```
babel.transform("[1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 2)", {presets: ["es2015"]}).code
```

you get

```
'"use strict";\n\n[1, 2, 3].map(function (n) {\n  return n * 2;\n});'
```

as a result.  Obviously this has newlines and "use strict" added which you may not want, so you'll either need to dig around the babel options documentation to see if it can be formatted exactly as you want, or do it yourself.

**EDIT**

How the babel presets work has now changed (see [deprication notice on npm for preset-2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) and [information on how to use preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/env/)).  The modified steps are:

```
npm install babel-core babel-preset-env -S
```

Then run node and enter

```
babel.transform("[1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 2)", {presets: ["env"]}).code
```

and you will get

```
'"use strict";\n\n[1, 2, 3].map(function (n) {\n  return n * 2;\n});'
```

as before.

Comment: npm ERR! 404 Not Found: babel-preset-2015@latest ?

Comment: Seems it is now deprecated (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015). I'll update the answer

Comment: @bluejayke I've edited the answer to bring it up to date.